# Multiple switch values inside a loop

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to write a switch statement that matches multiple integers in the same case. I have tried many different examples, have most recently landed on:

```
Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "*.$($extension)" | Where-Object {

    $name = $_.Name
    $pattern = '(\d{2,4})'
    $metric = ([regex]$pattern).Matches($name)
    $variable = $metric.Item(0)

    switch ($variable) {
        {291,292 -contains $_} {
            Write-Host "Skip these numbers...`n"
            break
        }
        default {
            #process other numbers
        }
    }
}
```

But this seems to get skipped and always ends up on the default bit after this, I cannot find a way to hit those two magic numbers and skip the rest of the code.

This switch statement is inside a `Get-ChildItem`, I'm wondering if this would mean that `$_` refers to the loop and not the switch? Running out of ideas, any advice would be appreciated. I think I'm running PowerShell 4 if that helps. Thanks

Comment: What is $variable? What does it contain?

Comment: What do you mean "inside a `Get-ChildItem`"? Do you mean it's inside a `ForEach-Object`? Please show your actual code.

Comment: $variable is an integer taken from a file name via regex. Let me add more info how the $variable is constructed

Comment: For what it is worth, I tried your code with $variable = 291 and it worked fine. We need to see more code.

Comment: Try forcing the coercion of $variable to [int]

Comment: I think you're right here, I've got another program that uses the same data and it matches each one individually, which is in quotes. The horror! Will give it a quick go

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to add -Exclude 29[12] to your Get-Childitem cmdlet?

Comment: Quite possibly, I hadn't considered that as an option, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @EBGreen the coercion to int worked, I'm sure I checked that previously!

Comment: For a short-answer, I think the reason all files were being returned is that a regex match is very noisey in PowerShell and always returns an object, causing everything the appear in your pipeline.  I propose a new approach in my new answer, to attack the problem a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New

Ok, I understand what you'd like to do.

So, as it turns out, the way Where-Object works is that you can put a filter block, just like in ForEach-Object, and if the filter emits and object, then matching objects continue down the pipeline.

With that being said, I think this would be **much** simpler as a Dir | Where | ForEach, rather than this much more complex mega-Where you've got going on.

In your example, you've got a regex looking for files which contain between 2 and 4 digits in them.  If the file contains the numbers 291, or 292, you don't want to process them.

To replicate this, i've got a directory full of ISO files, called 290.iso, 291.iso, 292.iso and so on.

If this works, we should see a list of ISOs retured at the end of the Pipeline, minus the ones with the 'offending' digits, which we do not want.

```
Dir t:\ 2*.iso | Where {$_.BaseName -match $pattern} | ForEach-Object{
    if ($_.BaseName -in (291,292)) {$null}
    else{$_}
    }
```

Results:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                 
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                 
-a----        12/1/2015  12:40 PM             12 290.iso                                                                                              
-a----        12/1/2015  12:40 PM             12 293.iso                                                                                              
-a----        12/1/2015  12:40 PM             12 294.iso                                                                                              
-a----        12/1/2015  12:40 PM             12 295.iso
```

So, in your case, you'd just add one more ForEach to the end of the pipeline to process these macros or whatever you'd like to do.

```
Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "*.$($extension)" | 
    Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match $pattern} |
         ForEach {
            #Dump the files is their name contains any of these numbers
            if ($_.BaseName -in (291,292)) {$null}
            else{$_}
            } | ForEach-Object {
                #Run your macros here
                }
```

Possibly a better approach would be to collect the files we DO want to work with in a variable, and then use ForEach on those.

```
#Only return files with numbers in the name
$MatchingFiles = Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter "*.$($extension)" | 
    Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match $pattern} 

#Remove files with 291, 292 in their name   
$FilteredFiles = $MatchingFiles | 
         ForEach {
            #Dump the files is their name contains any of these numbers
            if ($_.BaseName -in (291,292)) {$null}
            else{$_}
            } 

#Run the macros for each file remaining            
ForEach ($file in $FilteredFiles){
    #Run your macros here
    }
```

I know this doesn't answer your switch question, but I think this is a better approach to take.  I'd hate to inherit the working Switch you come up with to accomplish this task.

## OLD

This is kind of a strange usage of Where-Object, and if I may be totally honest, I'm not sure what this is attempting to accomplish.  I've found that you'll always get better answers here if you'll explain what your code wants to do.

That being said, this works for me if I change your Where-Object into a ForEach-Object.

Functionally, your switch works.  When I tested with this code structure:

```
forEach ($variable in (290..295)){
switch ($variable) {
        {291,292 -contains $_} {
            Write-Host "Skip these numbers... $variable"
            break
        }
        default {
            "We won't skip this one $variable"#process other numbers
        }
    }

    }
```

Output:

```
We won't skip this one 290
Skip these numbers.... 291
Skip these numbers.... 292
We won't skip this one 293
We won't skip this one 294
We won't skip this one 295
```

So, I think the problem is that you're using the wrong cmdlet for this job.  If I'm wrong and you have a good reason for using Where-Object, I'd love to learn it, so please let me know :)

Comment: Completely fair comment, I'm very new to PowerShell and writing/changing bits as I learn, I'm not a programmer by profession either, just trying to automate some manual work. The loop goes through each file in a folder full of excel spreadsheets and runs certain macros if the number from the file name matches. (I don't want to run the macros on all the reports). I concede a lot of context was probably missed as I'd rather not post the whole program.

Comment: Just seen your new answer, thank you very much for taking the time to explain this. Would much rather approach the solution better as a whole. Will take this in to consideration for version 2 (starting today...!)

Comment: How can I expand the second part so that it excludes filenames that contain 291 or 292, but it isn't necessarily their whole filename?

Comment: I changed $_.BaseName -in (291,292) to $_.BaseName -match '29(1|2)' and it works.

Comment: Here you go Chris.  The easy way to do this without weird -IN formatting is to change from using -IN, which checks to see if an item matches a list of files, to using -LIKE, which allows us to do a wild card search.  https://gist.github.com/1RedOne/0437b944345237889615

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the switch values to match into an array. This can be done using the *@* character As an example, this code

```
function checkSwitch($switchValue) {
    switch ($switchValue) {
        { @(291, 292) -contains $_ } {
            Write-Host "Case hit, moving on ..."
        }

        default {
            Write-Host "Nothing to see here"
        }
    }
}

checkSwitch 42
checkSwitch 291
checkSwitch 292
```

writes this output

```
Nothing to see here
Case hit, moving on ...
Case hit, moving on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$variable` is a regex match object, not an `[int]`

Try something like

```
[int]$variable.Value
```